# CDK bundle a Nestjs API inside a Nodejs Lambdalith

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nestjs, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm new to bundling nodejs Lambda functions.

In my CDK project I have a nestjs api project under `assets/api`.

i.e. I can `cd assets/api` and run my nestjs API locally

I want to bundle my nestjs API in a lambdalith and create a [LambdaRestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.LambdaRestApi.html).

I tried with the `aws-serverless-express`, and in `assets/api/src/lambda.ts` I have

```js
// assets/api/src/lambda.ts
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { createServer, proxy } from 'aws-serverless-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as express from 'express';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core/nest-factory';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Server } from 'http';

const server = express();

async function bootstrap(): Promise<Server> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));
  app.enableCors();
  await app.init();
  return createServer(server);
}

let cachedServer: Server;

export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    cachedServer = await bootstrap();
  }
  return proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
};
```

Then my Lambda function:

```js
// lib/nest-api.ts

const nestFunction = new Function(this, 'NestHandler', {
  code: Code.fromAsset('assets/api/src'),
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  handler: 'lambda.handler',
  vpc: this._vpc,
  memorySize: 3008,
});
// Have a rest API using this function
const api = new LambdaRestApi(this, 'NestApi', {
  handler: nestFunction,
  endpointConfiguration: {
    types: [EndpointType.REGIONAL]
  }
});
```

Everything deploys fine, but when I invoke the API test endpoint, I get

```
Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Error: Cannot find module 'lambda'
```

I tried switching to `NodejsFunction`:

```js
const nestFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, 'NestHandler', {
  entry: 'assets/api/src/lambda.ts',
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  handler: 'handler',
  vpc: this._vpc,
  memorySize: 3008,
});
```

And get loads of errors when trying to synth, such as:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@nestjs/microservices"

    assets/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:57:128:
      57 │ ...stMicroservice } = (0, load_package_util_1.loadPackage)('@nestjs/microservices', 'NestFactory', () => require('@nestjs/microservices'));
         ╵                                                                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "@nestjs/microservices" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which
  will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this
  "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.
```

There are dozens more, and I'm definitely not understanding nodejs lambda bundling with CDK.

What am I missing when it comes to bundling this Nodejs Lambda function? All my dependencies for the nestjs api are under `assets/api/package.json`

Comment: Do you have a lockfile with the dependencies as well?